# How to make Google crawlable AJAX pagination in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, ajax, seo

I have searched a lot and have found enough about it but I am unable to apply it.

I have an Ajaxhandler to request as:

```
..test.ashx?pagenumber=1
```

And I want to make it crawlable.

Answer (score 4):

The way you'd have to do it is to render a plain HTML navigation based pager. And then on-load (using javascript ... jquery would be good) convert all of the pager links to ajax. That way, when googlebot queries the page, it will be able to navigate all the links as they were originally rendered.